# Apache dynamic IP whitelist for specific directory and files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I am trying to whitelist IPs dynamically to grant access to a specific directory. A php script will be constantly modyfying the whitelist.txt file to add/remove entries.

I know the proper way handle this is with RewriteMap, but I am not sure how to set this up.

For example, I want users to access my site normally when they visit example.com, however I want to deny access to ALL users visiting anything in the block path/directory "http://example.com/block" EXCEPT for those IP addresses in whitelist.txt, additionally, those IP addresses in whitelist.txt will only have access to a specific folder and file inside the "block" directory, request e.g:

http://example.com/block/123/123.txt

I have tried the code below (this is a rough sketch, it is completely off and wrong I am sure, but just to get the idea):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\/block+\ ##apply rules only for /block directory

RewriteMap ipmap txt://var/whitelist.txt

RewriteCond ${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} ^\/([0-9]*).txt$ $1 [NC] ##check whitelist for matching IP AND specific dir and file

RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Of course this does not work. When I visit example.com my website goes to a infinite redirect loop.

The whitelist.txt file would look like this:

```
170.172.100.162 123
152.109.211.250 43
62.55.254.83 2345
227.202.162.48 32
203.52.248.55 533
```

So IP address 170.172.100.162 will have access to http://www.example.com/block/123/123.txt

IP address 152.109.211.250 will have access to http://www.example.com/block/43/43.txt

... and so on.

Comment: Look like, people doesn't look at `htaccess` question anymore, i'm looking at some question about `htaccess`, they have no answer even comments for months, glad anyone could help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played around a bit starting from your rules and got to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/block\/? 
# apply rules only for /block directory

RewriteMap ipmap txt:/var/whitelist.txt

RewriteCond ${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /block [R=403,L]
# redirect to /block with 403 when IP address not in the whitelist 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$ [NC]
# stops when the request finds a dot '.', assuming a file
RewriteCond ${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} ^\d+$ [NC]
# does the redirect only when the IP is in the whitelist
RewriteRule .* /block/${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}}/${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}}.txt [R=permanent,L] 
# will redirect everything from /block to /block/x/x.txt -> x = numeric value corresponding to the request IP from the whitelist.txt file
```

When tested it worked like this:

- accessed http://example.com -> no redirect, got to the index page
- accessed http://example.com/block -> redirected to http://example.com/block/123/123.txt and displayed txt file contents
- accessed http://example.com/block from different device on the network -> redirected to the corresponding entry from the whitelist file

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:

- when IP is not found in the whitelist.txt then a redirect to /block with 403 code is performed

**EDIT 2**:

At the moment any user with an IP from the whitelist.txt file can access other users directory. I've tried to find a condition for that but didn't really find anything. So what I can think of at the moment is having `.htaccess` files at directory level like this:

```
deny from all
allow from 1.2.3.4
#1.2.3.4 is arbitrary
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this and get back to you. Do you know if it possible to use a wildcard IP such as 170.172.100.0/24 ? Sometimes the last group of numbers vary.

Maybe using 170.172.100.* in the whitelist, but then how do I use that with the RewriteRule?

Comment: Also, with your solution, when accessed from a different device - what do you mean when it is redirected to the entry in the whitelist file? I want it to return a 403 access denied, but not redirect?

Comment: Different device in the network means different IP address. This way I tested how from a different IP its corresponding entry from the whitelist.txt file is feed into the RewriteRule.

Comment: I came up with this to work the way I want, but I have a small problem: the capture %1 is not working in the RewriteCond, I cannot figure out why.

Test url: http://example.com/block/0/1/file.txt
whitelist.txt: 170.172.100.12 1

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/block\/?
RewriteMap ipmap txt:/var/www/html/block/whitelist.txt
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/block\/[0-9]\/([0-9]*)\/
RewriteCond ${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} !^%1$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]`

Comment: @user969622 I have no idea why my solution is not working for you, I've tested it on OSX Apache 2.4.18 and Ubuntu Apache 2.4.7. Which OS / Apache version do you use?

Comment: Your solution is not doing what I need it to. I need to be able to access the file directly by going to "http://example.com/block/123/123.txt", also if the IP address is not in the whitelist it should be returning a 403 error. In your case it will not deny access rendering the whitelist pointless.

Comment: @user969622 I've edited my answer with a 403 error for when the IP is not in the whitelist